# custom quarter dates in sql

Tags: sql, date

I have data that I am trying to group at a custom quarter interval. The data is daily and in UTC time.  I can easily break it down by month, but I am have difficulty doing it at the quarter level. For example, the fiscal date needs to start on 3/22/2017 and run for 3 months. So the quarter should be from 3/22/17-6/22/17 and pull for all the other months as well.

I used this code for the month level:

```
        CASE    WHEN
        CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateutc) AS DATE))), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE))), 22)
        AND DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)), DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)), 21)
        THEN DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR(4))
        WHEN CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE) > DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)), DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE)), 21)
        THEN DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE))) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, c.dateUTC) AS DATE))) AS VARCHAR(4))
        END AS FiscalMonth
```

But having difficulty modifying to have the correct datesand code for quarter. Is there a simple fix I can make to change the existing query to quarter level.

Comment: Will your quarters always be skewed to 22/3, 22/6 etc. or will that change as well?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This might work, the idea is just to transform the input date on a normalized scale which starts on Jan 1. Just from the syntax posted I'm assuming SQL Server, but you should add the RDBMS tag.

ex.

```
SELECT '2017-03-22' AS Custom_strt,
       inputDate,
       DATEADD
         ( day,
           DATEDIFF(day, Custom_strt, Q1_strt),
           DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,Q1_strt, inputDate), inputDate)
         ) AS normalizedDate, 
       DATE '2017-01-01' AS Q1_strt,
       DATEADD(month, 3, Q1_strt) AS Q1_end,
       DATEADD(day, 1, Q1_end) AS Q2_strt,
       ...
       DATEADD(month, 3, Q4_strt) AS Q4_end,
       CASE WHEN normalizedDate BETWEEN Q1_strt AND Q1_end THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN normalizedDate BETWEEN Q2_strt AND Q2_end THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN normalizedDate BETWEEN Q3_strt AND Q3_end THEN 'Q3'
            WHEN normalizedDate BETWEEN Q4_strt AND Q1_end THEN 'Q4'
        END AS fiscal_quarter
  FROM SomeTable
```